# Using objects as the key and value in c++ maps

Tags: c++

I've got a class called `Transaction_List.cpp` which is supposed to map objects from two other classes. One of the other classes is `Date.cpp` which holds a date and time (EX: 1/29/2018 12:34:56) and a class `Transactions.cpp` which holds a double and a name (EX: 78.9 some-name).

In my **main** I have the following:

```
Transaction_List transactions {};   
Date d1 {1,29,2018,12,34,56};
Transaction t1 {9.75, "some name"};
if(transactions.add_transaction(d1,t1))
    cout << "transaction added" << endl;
```

In **Transaction_List.h** I have:

```
public:
bool add_transaction(Date d, Transaction t);
private:
map<Date, Transaction> transactions;
```

and lastly, in **Transaction_List.cpp**:

```
bool Transaction_List::add_transaction(Date d, Transaction t){
    cout << t.get_name() << endl;
    return transactions.insert(make_pair(d,t)).second;
}
```

In my **main.cpp** when I execute:

```
cout << t1.get_name();
```

(which I do have implemented properly, didn't include it because this post will be long enough as is), the correct name is output to the terminal. Similar can be said about any dates I create.

My problem is that when I try to execute:

```
cout << t.get_name() << endl;
```

in `Transaction_List.cpp`, it spits out garbage. Essentially any Date or Transaction I create is turned into garbage values upon being sent to `Transaction_List.cpp`.

If the previous is not sufficent information, [This link is to a google drive folder of all the files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fqSXeX6RFWI0Wzs-D8dEYiDjjJYAiYQL)

This is for a school assignment. What I'm supposed to have at the end of the day is a list of transactions associated with a particular date that I can search through, add too, and subtract from by date or by transaction.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That post contains too much text and not enough code.  Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Is the copy constructor working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed your link and investigated the code.

As @super points out, your copy constructor isn't working properly.  For your `Transaction.cpp`:

```
#include "Transaction.h"

...

Transaction::Transaction(double p, string n) {
    price = p;
    name = n;
}

// This is your implementation of the copy constructor
Transaction::Transaction(const Transaction& orig) {
}
```

Apparently, you are leaving the copy constructor of class `Transaction` empty. It seems that `Date`'s is also empty.

As a result, while executing this chunk of codes:

```
if(transactions.add_transaction(d1,t1))
    cout << "transaction added" << endl;
```

since you are passing objects of `Transaction` and `Date` by value, copy constructor of these two classes are called. However, because your copy constructors are empty, you actually add in a transaction object with two fields `price` and `name` uninitialized. That's why you are seeing strange values from the output.

To fix it, you can simply delete your copy constructor for `Transaction` and `Date`